# DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID while accepting payment from paypal using credit card

Tags: php, apache, rest, paypal

I am getting this error when I try to use my sandbox account on my local server to get credit card payments. I have no idea how to handle this any help will be appreciated. Here is the error I received:

```
int(400)
string(212) "{"name":"DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID","message":"PayPal-Request-Id header was already used.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID","debug_id":"2845e6fe9b1b5"}"
exception 'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\paypal1\lib\PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection.php:177
Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\paypal1\lib\PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall.php(73): PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{"intent":"sale...')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\paypal1\lib\PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel.php(102): PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL)
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\paypal1\lib\PayPal\Api\Payment.php(579): PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext), NULL)
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\paypal1\sample\index.php(66): PayPal\Api\Payment->create(Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext))
#4 {main}
```

Here is my index file:

```
<?php
    require 'bootstrap.php';
    use PayPal\Api\Amount;
    use PayPal\Api\CreditCard;
    use PayPal\Api\Details;
    use PayPal\Api\FundingInstrument;
    use PayPal\Api\Item;
    use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
    use PayPal\Api\Payer;
    use PayPal\Api\Payment;
    use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

    $card = new CreditCard();
    $card->setType("visa")
        ->setNumber("43111*******44663")
        ->setExpireMonth("09")
        ->setExpireYear("2021")
        ->setCvv2("012")
        ->setFirstName("My")
        ->setLastName("Name");

    $fi = new FundingInstrument();
    $fi->setCreditCard($card);

    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod("credit_card")
        ->setFundingInstruments(array($fi));

    $product = "rambo dfdf";
    $price = 305;
    $shipping = 2.00;
    $total = $price + $shipping;

    $item = new Item();
    $item->setName($product)
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice($price);

    $itemList = new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems([$item]);

    $details = new Details();
    $details->setShipping($shipping)
    ->setSubtotal($price);

    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setTotal($total)
    ->setDetails($details);

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($itemList)
        ->setDescription("Payment description")
        ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent("sale")
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    $request = clone $payment;

    try {
        $payment->create($apiContext);
    } catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($ex->getCode());  // Prints the Error Code
        var_dump( $ex->getData()); // Prints the detailed error message 
        die($ex);
        echo "</pre>";
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo "<pre>";
        die($ex);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    return $payment;
```

Here is my bootstrap.php file:

```
<?php
/*
 * Sample bootstrap file.
 */

// Include the composer Autoloader
// The location of your project's vendor autoloader.
$composerAutoload = dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))) . '/autoload.php';
if (!file_exists($composerAutoload)) {
    //If the project is used as its own project, it would use rest-api-sdk-php composer autoloader.
    $composerAutoload = dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';


    if (!file_exists($composerAutoload)) {
        echo "The 'vendor' folder is missing. You must run 'composer update' to resolve application dependencies.\nPlease see the README for more information.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}
require $composerAutoload;
require __DIR__ . '/common.php';

use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;

// Suppress DateTime warnings, if not set already
date_default_timezone_set(@date_default_timezone_get());

// Adding Error Reporting for understanding errors properly
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// Replace these values by entering your own ClientId and Secret by visiting https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps
$clientId = '*******************************';
$clientSecret = '****************************';

/**
 * All default curl options are stored in the array inside the PayPalHttpConfig class. To make changes to those settings
 * for your specific environments, feel free to add them using the code shown below
 * Uncomment below line to override any default curl options.
 */
//PayPalHttpConfig::$defaultCurlOptions[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2;


/** @var \Paypal\Rest\ApiContext $apiContext */
$apiContext = getApiContext($clientId, $clientSecret);

return $apiContext;
/**
 * Helper method for getting an APIContext for all calls
 * @param string $clientId Client ID
 * @param string $clientSecret Client Secret
 * @return PayPal\Rest\ApiContext
 */
function getApiContext($clientId, $clientSecret)
{

    // #### SDK configuration
    // Register the sdk_config.ini file in current directory
    // as the configuration source.
    /*
    if(!defined("PP_CONFIG_PATH")) {
        define("PP_CONFIG_PATH", __DIR__);
    }
    */


    // ### Api context
    // Use an ApiContext object to authenticate
    // API calls. The clientId and clientSecret for the
    // OAuthTokenCredential class can be retrieved from
    // developer.paypal.com

    $apiContext = new ApiContext(
        new OAuthTokenCredential(
            $clientId,
            $clientSecret
        )
    );

    // Comment this line out and uncomment the PP_CONFIG_PATH
    // 'define' block if you want to use static file
    // based configuration

    $apiContext->setConfig(
        array(
            'mode' => 'sandbox',
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => '../PayPal.log',
            'log.LogLevel' => 'DEBUG', // PLEASE USE `INFO` LEVEL FOR LOGGING IN LIVE ENVIRONMENTS
            'cache.enabled' => true,
            // 'http.CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT' => 30
            // 'http.headers.PayPal-Partner-Attribution-Id' => '123123123'
            //'log.AdapterFactory' => '\PayPal\Log\DefaultLogFactory' // Factory class implementing \PayPal\Log\PayPalLogFactory
        )
    );

    // Partner Attribution Id
    // Use this header if you are a PayPal partner. Specify a unique BN Code to receive revenue attribution.
    // To learn more or to request a BN Code, contact your Partner Manager or visit the PayPal Partner Portal
    // $apiContext->addRequestHeader('PayPal-Partner-Attribution-Id', '123123123');

    return $apiContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the request id by replacing

```
$payment->create($apiContext);
```

With

```
$apiContext->resetRequestId();    
$payment->create($apiContext);
```

Comment: no, it's still the same error popping up on the browser